# How to initialize an array of ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

Im designing an UWP movie app and i need several ObservableCollections to store different movie lists. I wanna use ObservableCollection[Index], but dont know how to initialize it.
I've tried the following code but failed:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Subject>[] FullMovieList = new ObservableCollection<Subject>[6];
```

How can i accomplish it? Thx~

Comment: `failed` - could u mention what error you got?

Comment: i cant remember exactly, it's mainly about nullexception or so :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create array of `ObservableCollection<Subject>` correctly.
But you create array only, not collection in array itself.

You should create collections also;

```
for (int a = 0; a < FullMovieList.Length; a++)
{
    FullMovieList[a] = new ObservableCollection<Subject>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a new collection each time you want to add range of objects is not good rather i would follow below design.

Build a class inheriting from `ObservableCollection` , so that you can access Items property which is protected and then create a `AddRange` method which will add items into it

```
public class MyObObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }    
    }

    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
}
```